# How to disable ctrl shift t in google chrome windows 10

Tags: google-chrome

I want to disable ctrl shift t
so when I close a tab it cannot be reopened I tried going into setting but could not find a solution.

Comment: Use Incognito mode: Ctrl+Shift+N. Browser history is not saved (among other things) and tabs cannot be re-opened using Ctrl+Shift+T.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a feature to disable keyboard shortcuts.

One option that's more of a workaround than a fix is to remap the shortcut.

This can be done by going to chrome://extensions and selecting the "Keyboard Shortcuts" option. From there, you can select an extension to map the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut to.

This, however, only disables the functionality, not the data behind it. This still exists in the history, unless you're in InCognito mode.